# How to disable back button in iOS mono

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to show semiview from my parent page & want to disable all the interaction including back button. How to disable back button? I know how to hide it but i don't want to hide.I want to disable it.So when user touch it,it doesn't to anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This discussion the Xamarin Forums might help: 
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18079/how-to-block-to-go-to-previous-screen

Recommends looking into Navigation.PushModalAsync();

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AXamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushModalAsync(Xamarin.Forms.Page)

Hope this helps.